# what does this mean in PHP ()->

Tags: php, oop

I've seen this use of syntax a few times on the Yii framework. I tried searching for an explanation but got no examples. A link will be nice if possible. It goes something like `class::model()->function();`

My understanding is that model is an object of class therefore it can access the function. So I tried to code it but I get " Call to a member function `sound()` on a non-object in". Here's my code

```
class animal
{
    private static $obj;

    public static function obj($className = __CLASS__)
    {        
        return self::$obj;
    }

    public static function walk()
    { 
        return "walking"; 
    } 
}


include('animal.php');

class cat extends animal
{
    public static function obj($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::obj($className);
    }

    public static function sound()
    {
        return "meow";
    }
}

echo cat::obj()->sound();
```

Also what benefits does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo cat::obj()->sound();
```

This will display the output of the `sound()` method, called on the object that is returned from `cat::obj()`.

The reason it's failing for you is because `cat::obj()` is not returning a valid object.

And the reason for that is because the `obj()` method returns the static `obj` property, but you're not actually setting that `obj` property anywhere.

The pattern you're trying to use here is known as a "Singleton" object. In this pattern, you call an `obj()` method to get the single instance of the class; every call to the method will give you the same object.

However the first call to the method needs to instantiate the object; this is what you're missing.

```
public static function obj($className = __CLASS__){
    if(!static::$obj) {static::$obj = new static;}
    return static::$obj;
}
```

See the new line where the object is created if it doesn't exist.

Also note that I've changed `self` to `static`. The way you're using this with class inheritance means that you probably expect to have a different static object for each class type, `self` will always return the root `animal::$obj` property, whereas `static` will return the `$obj` property for whichever class you're calling it from.

There are a few other bugs you need to watch out for too. For example, you've defined the `sound()` method as `static`, but you're calling it with `->`, so it shouldn't be static.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That explained so much, I done if(!self::$obj) {self::$obj = new $className;}
    return self::$obj; and it worked. The static version is giving me "Cannot access property cat::$obj" Should I change something in cat class

Comment: What PHP version are you using? `static` was only introduced in PHP 5.3, so if you're on an older version it won't work. (but you should not be on an older version than that, because 5.2 has been unsupported for three years already, so if you're not on 5.3, this is your cue to upgrade)

Comment: It's Version PHP 5.3.8

Answer (score 6):

That is called an **object operator** and this, `->`, calls a class method from your created object which is defined in that class.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) is an explanation and some examples.

```
$obj = new Class; // Object of the class
$obj->classMethod(); // Calling a method from that class with the object
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you be able to show me an example or a link?

Comment: @A.Mo Posted a link, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The `cat::obj()` returns you a object of the type cat. With `->sound();` you're executing the function sound() from the class cat. All that should return "meow".

Answer (score 0):

`cat::obj()` returns an object; `->sound();` execute a method of this object. Equivalent is

```
$o = cat::obj();
$o->sound();
```

Comment: the method sound() should not be static. so either we should remove the keyword "static" from the definition, or, call it with `$o::sound();`

Comment: @Asenar You are correct, this is notice or warning. However `$o::sound();` would not work.